# SQL Query to get userCount who have visited the site more than 2 times before the instant when it is checked

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, grafana

I have a table where we keep the log every time a user visit the page. We want to get count of users who have already visited the site more than 1 times.
Let say a user visited site on 1st and then on 3rd August. Now on 2nd Aug, the user will not be counted as he has only 1 visit till now. So total count of user who visited more than 1 times will be 0 only for 2nd Aug.
But for 4th Aug, since the user have visited the site more than 1 time, the user count will be 1.

I am actually tying to get this done as daily  user count trend on Grafana.

The SQL query I wrote is giving:

> error querying the database: ERROR: This type of correlated subquery pattern is not supported yet

SQL Query:

```
select date_trunc('day', timestamp) as day_value, 
   count(distinct distinct_id) 
   from posthog_event where 
   timestamp BETWEEN '2022-08-09T22:15:43Z' AND '2022-08-10T22:15:43Z'  and 
   distinct_id IN 
   (select distinct_id from(select distinct_id, count(*) as event_count from 
   posthog_event innertable 
   where innertable.timestamp < day_value and event = 'visited' group by 1) 
   where event_count>2) 
   group by day_value order by day_value
```

[Grafana](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GTpS.png) image showing the error and query

Datasource is Redshift.

Comment: Please only tag a **single** RDBMS... not multiple.

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using a SUM() OVER() window function?  This seems like the simplest way to do this.

Comment: Not sure about the usage of Sum() and over() window function. Can you please help? @BillWeiner

Comment: I can give a more detailed answer later today but it sounds like looking at the window function docs would be helpful.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_Window_functions.html

Comment: Thanks. @BillWeiner I will go through the doc and will try to get implement query using it meanwhile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've put together a simplified case of detecting 2nd (or greater) visit.  I expect you can modify to meet your specific use case.

Set up:

```
create table mytable (
  id int,   
  visit_date date);
  
insert into mytable values
(1, '2022-01-01'),
(2, '2022-01-02'),
(3, '2022-01-03'),
(1, '2022-01-04'),
(1, '2022-01-09'),
(2, '2022-01-10'),
(3, '2022-01-11')
;
```

Count visits by id:

```
select id, visit_date,
      count(1) over(partition by id order by visit_date) as num_visits
from mytable
order by visit_date;
```

This produces the number of times an id visited.  (Yes I changed to COUNT() OVER() as this was simplest.)  You will likely need to do some data grouping by date before performing the window function.

Comment: I am getting "error querying the database: ERROR: Aggregate window functions with an ORDER BY clause require a frame clause" when running on my data.

Comment: But on running the Query with dummy data(like the table you created), I am getting expected results with TimescaleDB.

Comment: Are you using COUNT() OVER() or SUM() OVER()?  The COUNT() window function has an implicit frame clause but some others, like SUM(), do not.  If you update the question with the SQL you are currently using I can take a look.  If not, I expect that you likely want a frame clause like "rows unbounded preceding" but this is only a guess.  Window functions are really powerful, straight forward once you "get them", but can seem quite complex until you do "get them".

Comment: I am using the count()  over() window function: 
select distinct_id, timestamp as ts,
count(1) over(partition by distinct_id order by ts) as num_search_visits
from posthog_event
order by ts

Comment: I see.  There is likely some other aspect in the rest of the query that is driving the need for the frame clause.  Like you said it's not dummy data.  This is straight forward - "count(1) over(partition by distinct_id order by ts rows unbounded preceding)".  This has the exact same meaning as when it is not included, it just makes things clearer to the the query compiler.

Comment: On adding "rows unbounded preceding" to the query, i am getting "Metric request error"

Comment: Can you please suggest another way/sql query to get desired result for the same use case?

Comment: The "Metric request error" is gone when i moved from timeseries to table visualization.
I came up with following query for the actual problem posted, but not sure if it doing it right.  SQL:
``` 
select ts, count (distinct distinct_id) from
(
  select distinct_id, ts from 
  (
  select distinct_id, date_trunc('day', timestamp) as ts,
      count(1) over(partition by distinct_id order by ts rows unbounded preceding ) as num_search_visits
  from posthog_event
  where event='Search'
  order by ts
  ) where num_search_visits>3
)
where $__timeFilter(ts)
group by ts
order by ts 
```

Comment: "Metric request error" looks like it is coming from your BI tool.  The query looks ok but I have a few questions.  I see that you have "num_search_visits>3" which doesn't match what I would have expected given your question but may be related to question #2.  You truncate the timestamp down to a date but you didn't do anything to get distinct activity per date.  So you may be able to get multiple rows for the same id on the same date.  Seems like some pre-conditioning on the data might be needed.

Comment: By doing num_search_visits > 3 i will get all those users who have visited the site for than 3 times, although repeated. But since I am doing distinct count on them, so i shall be getting expected count, isn't it?

Comment: I don't have a great understanding of your data or your needs.  That said I'm guessing you want to find ids that visit on more than 3 days and that 4 times in a single day isn't what you are looking for.  The query as written won't distinguish between these cases.  The DISTINCT isn't until the outer SELECT but the count is performed on the inner SELECT where dates (ts) can have repeated values.  Maybe this case isn't possible in your data but it is common with this type of data based on timestamps to allow multiple "visits" per day.

Comment: Yes, I need ids that visit for more than 3 times (be it in same day or be it  over a week. On the day when I am looking at data, i need people who have visited more than 3 time upto that day)

Comment: SQL Query: (select distinct_id, date_trunc('day', timestamp) as ts,count(1) over(partition by distinct_id order by ts rows unbounded preceding ) as num_search_visits from posthog_event where event='Search' order by ts)
Will give me the num_search_visits by ids. Now if  I take only those ids which shows num_search_visits>3 , i will get those who have visited the site more than 3 times. With this data, i will also have timestamp(truncated to day) and if I group by  them with truncated time, i will get the unique count of people per day with more than 3 searches. 
What do you think?

Comment: Yes this makes sense now.  I think the confusion comes from using (and having) the truncated timestamp in the inner select.  The order by in the window function is on this date (not the timestamp) which implies to me that this is needed on a date granularity.  The truncate could be done in the outer select but this is just a style point.

Comment: I am stuck on to get a combination of the above query with another condition. I needed the count of those users(on per day basis) who had searched on the site for more than X time (here  3)  and also who has more than Y  sessions (here say 3). We can identify a session using event = 'session'. 
Since we receive different rows for both these different events(one for session creation and one for search), I am finding it hard to get the count. 
I can get the user count  separately for them, but could not figure out how we can have the two condition together.

Comment: I don't have enough information on what you have already done nor the full situation that I can provide advice here.  If you can provide an update that has some sample input and expected output data along with the current query and a specific question to address I think the community can help.  Or you can hire some SQL writer or trainer that can dig into your situation with you.

Comment: I'm happy to help in either capacity